# Unable to read properties file from resource folder

Tags: java, properties, fileinputstream

I am using java 7, eclipse and maven. For my workspace locally the folder structure is like

```
             ---Project
                       ----src
                           ----Package
                              ---main class
                       ----resources
                           -----config.properties
```

In my eclipse I am reading properties from config.properties file in resource folder like below

```
   inputStream = Application.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
```

and this works completely fine.Now when I execute and build jar on Linux environemnt the config.properties file has to be an external location so getresourceAsStream method wont work as properties file is at another location.In linux Environment the properties file can ve read with FileInputStream

```
inputStream =  new FileInputStream("config.properties");
```

So in local I am working with getResourceAsStream method for reading properties and in linux I am using new FileInputStream.Can anyone help me how can I work in eclipse?Where should I put my config.properties file so that it can work with the FileInputStream.

Thanks

Comment: You should not be depending on the file system.  That won't work if you package your app.  InputStream from classpath is always the way to go.

Comment: @duffymo I didnt get you.What needs to be corrected here?

Comment: Don't do this: inputStream =  new FileInputStream("config.properties");

Comment: @duffymo But in linux I am using properties file which will be outside jar in the same folder.like opt/data/project/config.properties and  opt/data/project/jar.How to access properties then both in eclipse and in linux environement.?Thanks in advance

Comment: Eclipse is irrelevant.  The JAR requires that you get it from the CLASSPATH.  You can do the same in Eclipse or anywhere else that putting that .properties file in the CLASSPATH.  If you're using standard Maven directory structure this is easy: Put it in the main/resources folder.

Comment: BTW, JDK 7 has passed the end of its support life.  You should only be using JDK 8 now.

Comment: @duffymo I want properties file to be chnaged whenever required by the operation team.That why on linux I am keeping jar and properties file together.How can I put it in classpath then?Sorry I didnt understood your comment completly.